# Ensuring MQTT messages are always sent, even when broker is down

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I have an application when I'm sending MQTT messages to an IoT platform, the IoT platform has their own broker. The problem arose when the broker went down for 2-3 days, with that I lost 2-3 days worth of data.

I was wondering if there was a way to ensure that all data points are stored, and then sent when the broker come back online in order. I've been testing this with Mosquitto, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Is it a matter of using Quality of Service (QoS)? Does this work even the broker is down, or does it need the broker to communicate with? Or do I need to use persistence or retain?

Comment: This will be a property of the MQTT client library you are using, not the broker (since it's down it can't do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track, it requires QoS and must be used with the other settings together, you can test under the following conditions:

1. Initialize your MQTT client with clean session flag set to `False` and a unique client ID;

   Here is an example using Paho python library,

   ```sh
   mqttc = mqtt.Client("specify_a_unique_client_id", clean_session=False)
   ```
2. Subscribe to a topic with QoS >= 1;
3. Publish to a topic with QoS >= 1;

**NOTICE: you must specify a unique client ID**, so that your broker can still recognize the previous client session in case it reconnects. Leave the client ID as empty will auto generate a new one.

**Bonus**, Here is a good series of [articles](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/understanding-mqtt-qos-levels-part-1/) to explain all the configurations in MQTT, in case you want to understand the details.